# Exporting shapefile/feature class polygon to XY pairs/ASCII

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.6, ascii

For a polygon shapefile, I'm needing a polygon vertex coordinate output file like this for a legacy program:

```
polygon1, AUTO
  -120.3434    34.694354
  -120.3750    34.694354
  -120.3750    34.713433
  -120.3434    34.713433
END
polygon2, AUTO
  -121.3434    35.694354
  -121.3750    35.694354
  -121.3750    35.713433
  -121.3434    35.713433
END
```

When I try `Spatial Statistics Tool`'s `Export Feature Attribute to ASCII`, however, the output looks like output for a point file, ie just one XY pair for each polygon (each polygon has many vertices). In another program I could add in the `, AUTO` and `END` pieces - I'm needing most just how to export the XY polygon pairs.

I've come across an `Ungenerate` tool that might be another starting point, but ArcMap 10.6 won't seem to open it from the tool search display, and also a `Feature Vertices to Points` tool, but looks like that requires the Advanced license.

Any ideas?

Comment: Advanced: Requires ArcInfo Workstation installed > http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/coverage-toolbox/ungenerate.htm

Comment: ET GeoWIzards (at cost) still works for 10.6 https://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/ETGW12UG_WEB/etgw/Ungenerate_Wizard.htm

Comment: The code samples for [Reading geometries](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python/reading-geometries.htm#GUID-9FC74E09-898D-4A5E-9A07-76CD911C2AC6) have much of what you need -- You'd just need to format it a bit.